# Overfull \hbox while using the "quotation" environment in a beamer document

Tags: beamer, boxes, warnings, quotation

Why is is that I get a `Overfull \hbox` warning whenever I use a `quotation` environment within a list in Beamer? Take, for instance, this file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Example}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item See:
   \begin{quotation}
      \lipsum[1]
   \end{quotation}
 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If I compile it, I get the warning

```
Overfull \hbox (21.90005pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 12--12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a very long paragraph, it is not that surprising that the contents overflows the page. If you put your `quotation` environment inside a `\fbox` which will show a frame around its content, you see that it add quite large margin.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Example}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item See:
   \fbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{%
       \begin{quotation}
      \lipsum[1]
   \end{quotation}
   }}
 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want a slightly more flexible solution, you can try the [quoting](https://ctan.org/pkg/quoting) package.

You can take advantage of the `leftmargin/rightmargin` options which allow to customize the local margins with respect to the current `\textwidth`.

See below

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[leftmargin=0pt,rightmargin=0pt]{quoting}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Example}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item See:
              \begin{quoting}
                  \lipsum[1]
              \end{quoting}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]